# Radio buttons binding in .Net MAUI: selected item is not updated in the view model

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

I have a .Net MAUI app that uses CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.

Here is a part of my view model:

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    private DateTime _selectedTime;

    public List<DateTime> Times { get; set; } = new ()
        { new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 9, 30, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 10, 30, 0),
          new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 11, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 11, 30, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 30, 0),
          new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 13, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 13, 30, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 14, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 14, 30, 0),
          new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 15, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 15, 30, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 16, 0, 0), new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 16, 30, 0) };
```

Here is a part of the page:

```
        <CollectionView 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Times}" 
            SelectionMode="Single"
            ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 3">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <RadioButton Content="{Binding ., StringFormat='{0:hh:mm tt}'}">
                            <RadioButton.IsChecked>
                                <Binding Path="BindingContext.SelectedTime"
                                     Source="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:AppointmentSchedulePage}}" 
                                     Converter="{StaticResource DateTimeConverter}"
                                     ConverterParameter="{Binding .}" 
                                     Mode="TwoWay"/>
                            </RadioButton.IsChecked>
                        </RadioButton>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

Here is the converter:

```
public class DateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is DateTime selectedDateTime && parameter is DateTime itemDateTime)
        {
            return selectedDateTime.Equals(itemDateTime);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool isChecked && isChecked && parameter is DateTime itemDateTime)
        {
            return itemDateTime;
        }

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Though I am not sure that the converter is needed in my scenario.

The radio buttons are displayed correctly:

[image]

But the SelectedTime property in the viewmodel is not updated, and its setter is not hit.
What am I missing?

Comment: Off-topic-tip: Consider using `TimeSpan` instead of `DateTime` to represent time-of-day values.

Comment: What do you see in the VS _XAML Binding Errors_ window at runtime?

Comment: @Dai With TimeSpan, I cannot display the value like "10:00 AM". Or am I missing something? Nothing appears in XAML Binding Failures window.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry - I forgot that `TimeSpan`'s `ToString()` doesn't support time-of-day formatting.

Comment: You need to tell collectionview what to do when an item is clicked. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/selection Set SelectionChanged to a method. In that method, set SelectedItem to the item that was clicked. See that doc for details. SIDE-NOTE: Your ItemTemplate doesn't need `<Grid>` if there is only one element (RadioButton).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thank you for your suggestion. Does it mean that there is no way to bind selected radio button to a property, like e.g. with datetimepicker or listbox?

Comment: I've added an answer. Not tested.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks, I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [RadioButton / Respond to a property change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/radiobutton#respond-to-a-property-change).

If you **group** radio buttons (assign them to the same group), then you can **bind** to the selected value of the `RadioButtonGroup`:

```xml
<CollectionView RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="MyGroup"
        RadioButtonGroup.SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedRadioButton}">
    ...
    <DataTemplate>
        <RadioButton GroupName="MyGroup" ... />
```

```cs
// Try this first with type "object", and see what it gets set to.
// Then maybe can change it to a specific type; not sure.
public object SelectedRadioButton { get; set; }
```

NOTE: Because the buttons are inside `ItemTemplate`/`DataTemplate`, tell each one the groupname; AFAIK that is not automatically passed down from collectionview into the datatemplate.

Comment: The above does not work for me because the RadioButtonGroup.SelectedValue only works when put on an object that inherits from ILayout. To solve this you can just wrap the CollectionView within another layout component that does inherit from ILayout, such as VerticalStackLayout. You'd then move the RadioButtonGroup... attributes to that layout.